# Implementation of Euler Totient function in OpenMP

Tags: c++, openmp

I am new to OpenMP and I am trying to implement Euler Totient function in OpenMP.
This is my first attempt to code in OpenMP. My goal is to implement it in parallel (fastest, if possible) and then in sequential. After that I calculate the speedup and efficiency.
Below is my code:

```
/*
 ============================================================================
 Name        : 55390_ass3.cpp
 Author      : Kamil Kamili
 Version     :
 Copyright   : Your copyright notice
 Description : Euler’s Totient function φ(n) in OpenMP
 ============================================================================
 */
#include <omp.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int eulerTotient(int number)
{
        int sNumber = number;
        for(int i = 2; i*i <= number; ++i)
        {
                if(number % i == 0)
                {
                        while(number % i == 0)
                        {
                                number /= i;
                        }
                }
        }
        if(number > 1)
        {
                sNumber -= sNumber / number;
        }
        return sNumber;
}

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
        int nTheads = omp_get_num_threads();
        int nMaxThreads = omp_get_max_threads();
        printf("Parallel Execution: \n");
        double startTimeForParallel = omp_get_wtime();
#pragma omp parallel for
         for(int i = 2; i < 10000; i++)
         {
                 printf("φ(%d) = %d\n", i, eulerTotient(i));
         }
         double parallelTime = omp_get_wtime() - startTimeForParallel;
         printf("Sequential Execution: \n");
         double startTimeForSequential = omp_get_wtime();
         for(int i = 2; i < 10000; i++)
                  {
                          printf("φ(%d) = %d\n", i, eulerTotient(i));
                  }
         double sequentialTime = omp_get_wtime() - startTimeForSequential;
         double speedUp = sequentialTime/parallelTime;
         printf("Parallel Execution Time: ",parallelTime);
         printf("Sequential Execution Time: " << sequentialTime);
         printf("SpeedUp: "<<speedUp);
 return 0;
}
```

But it does not calculate 'Parallel Time'. Any idea where I am going wrong?

So I edited my code a bit here and there after doing some research. I think I am not using the function `omp_get_wtime()` correctly.

**By Edited Code:**

```
#include <omp.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
double omp_get_wtime(void);

int eulerTotient(int number)
{
        int sNumber = number;
        for(int i = 2; i*i <= number; ++i)
        {
                if(number % i == 0)
                {
                        while(number % i == 0)
                        {
                                number /= i;
                        }
                }
        }
        if(number > 1)
        {
                sNumber -= sNumber / number;
        }
        return sNumber;
}

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
        int nTheads = omp_get_num_threads();
        int nMaxThreads = omp_get_max_threads();
        printf("Parallel Execution: %f\n");
        double parallelTime, endTimeForParallel;
        double startTimeForParallel = omp_get_wtime();
#pragma omp parallel for
         for(int i = 2; i < 10000; i++)
         {
                 printf("O(%d) = %d\n", i, eulerTotient(i));
         }
         endTimeForParallel = omp_get_wtime();
         parallelTime = startTimeForParallel = endTimeForParallel;


        printf("Sequential Execution: \n");
        double sequentialTime,endTimeForSequential,startTimeForSequential = omp_get_wtime();
        for(int i = 2; i < 10000; i++)
        {
                printf("O(%d) = %d\n", i, eulerTotient(i));
        }
        endTimeForSequential = omp_get_wtime();
        sequentialTime = startTimeForSequential - endTimeForSequential;
        printf("Parallel Execution Time: %f seconds\n", parallelTime);
        printf("Sequential Execution Time: %f seconds\n", sequentialTime);
        double speedUp = sequentialTime/parallelTime;
        printf("SpeedUp: %f\n\n",speedUp);
        return 0;
}
```

The output is simply bizarre. Anyways, here it is:

```
Parallel Execution Time: 1477476938.765000 seconds
Sequential Execution Time: -0.099000 seconds
SpeedUp: -0.000000
```

**So a very noob mistake: Fixed it**

As stated by @Gilles. I fixed my code. Here it is:

```
/*
 ============================================================================
 Name        : 55390_ass3.c
 Author      : Kamil Kamili
 Version     :
 Copyright   : Your copyright notice
 Description : Euler Totient's function in C
 ============================================================================
 */
#include <omp.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
double omp_get_wtime(void);

int eulerTotient(int number)
{
        int sNumber = number;
        for(int i = 2; i*i <= number; ++i)
        {
                if(number % i == 0)
                {
                        while(number % i == 0)
                        {
                                number /= i;
                        }
                }
        }
        if(number > 1)
        {
                sNumber -= sNumber / number;
        }
        return sNumber;
}

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
        int nTheads = omp_get_num_threads();
        int nMaxThreads = omp_get_max_threads();
        printf("Parallel Execution: %f\n");
        double parallelTime, endTimeForParallel;
        double startTimeForParallel = omp_get_wtime();
#pragma omp parallel for
         for(int i = 2; i < 10000; i++)
         {
                 printf("O(%d) = %d\n", i, eulerTotient(i));
         }
         endTimeForParallel = omp_get_wtime();
         parallelTime = endTimeForParallel - startTimeForParallel;


        printf("Sequential Execution: \n");
        double sequentialTime,endTimeForSequential,startTimeForSequential = omp_get_wtime();
        for(int i = 2; i < 10000; i++)
        {
                printf("O(%d) = %d\n", i, eulerTotient(i));
        }
        endTimeForSequential = omp_get_wtime();
        sequentialTime = endTimeForSequential - startTimeForSequential;
        printf("Parallel Execution Time: %f seconds\n", parallelTime);
        printf("Sequential Execution Time: %f seconds\n", sequentialTime);
        double speedUp = sequentialTime/parallelTime;
        printf("SpeedUp: %f\n\n",speedUp);
        return 0;
}
```

And the output:

```
Parallel Execution Time: 0.014000 seconds
Sequential Execution Time: 0.095000 seconds
SpeedUp: 6.785746
```

I still think something is wrong, unless someone tells me otherwise.

Comment: Explain what "does not calculate time" mean.

Comment: hum, what is `printf("Sequential Execution Time: " << sequentialTime);` supposed to mean? This looks suspiciously like some happy mix-up between C and C++ style of printing.

Comment: I am trying to calculate how much time it takes to complete the loop in parallel execution and then the same loop in sequential execution. So i am measuring the time using `omp_get_wtime()` for both of them and then simply printing them using printf function.

Comment: Yeah, then try `printf("Sequential Execution Time: %f\n", sequentialTime);` etc.

Comment: my problem is that the `parallelTime` is not giving me anything.

Comment: @KamilKamili printf("Parallel Execution Time: %f\n",parallelTime); you misuse printf parameters.

Comment: Just take 2 minutes to re-read your code and all will become clear... Just look at  `parallelTime = startTimeForParallel = endTimeForParallel;` and also `sequentialTime = startTimeForSequential - endTimeForSequential;` Fix this and you'll see.